# Image display from local video file in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, avfoundation

I'm beginner in swift and objective-c, so trying to develop an application.
My rough idea is as follows:

video(file/URL) -> extract a frame image -> image processing -> display(UIImageView)

psuedocode: @ viewDidLoad

`while ( until end of frame )
{
        extract a frame (using copyCGImage function)
        // call image processing function
        ImageView.image = frame image after image processing.
}`

However, I check the final frame image after simulation this code.
Besides, using the animationImage function, memory size is not only dependent only video length but result is not perfect (the change of image is not smooth).

**Question:**
How to display extracted image files like original video in swift?

Comment: Your question is how to convert a sequence os images into a movie (m4v) ?

Comment: Why would you extract images from a video and then display them back as a movie? Is there a reason for this? You could simply play back the movie itself, right? But if you did want to show a series of images as an animation, then you can use the `animationImages` property in `UIImageView` to pass it an array of `UIImage` objects.

Comment: Thanks for response. For this working, I need to modified image. For example, I want to extract and display the only foreground image in video file. 
For this reason, I firstly wonder to display sequential image not to make video file. If my idea is impossible, I think to another method.